# Xamarin Android: Using a botton navigation view to delete a selected recyclerview item

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I've implemented a `RecyclerView` and on my page I've inserted a bottom navigation which have a delete button that i would like to delete the recycler view items that are selected. I wrote code where I get the position the item but when I use:

`mEmails.RemoveAt(position);`

nothing is happening.

How can I use bottom navigation view to delete a recycler view selected items?

My RecyclerView Adapter:

```
  public class RecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter, View.IOnClickListener
{
    private List<Email> mEmails;
    private Activity mActivity;
    public static int listPosition;

    private Boolean isSelected = false;

    public Boolean IsSelected()
    {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(Boolean selected)
    {

        isSelected = selected;
    }

    public RecyclerAdapter(List<Email> emails, Activity activity)
    {
        mEmails = emails;
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    public override int ItemCount => mEmails.Count;

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View row = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.row, parent, false);
        RecyclerViewHolder view = new RecyclerViewHolder(row);
        return view;
    }
    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        RecyclerViewHolder myHolder = holder as RecyclerViewHolder;
        myHolder.mDate.Text = ((Email)mEmails[position]).date;
        myHolder.mSubject.Text = ((Email)mEmails[position]).Subject;
        myHolder.mMessage.Text = ((Email)mEmails[position]).Message;

        myHolder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(((Email)mEmails[position]).IsSelected() ? Color.LightBlue : Color.Transparent);
        myHolder.ItemView.Tag = position;
        myHolder.ItemView.SetOnClickListener(this);
    }

    void View.IOnClickListener.OnClick(View v)
    {
        int position = (int)v.Tag;
        listPosition = (int)v.Tag;

        ((Email)mEmails[position]).setSelected(!((Email)mEmails[position]).IsSelected());
        v.SetBackgroundColor(((Email)mEmails[position]).IsSelected() ? Color.LightBlue : Color.Transparent);

        Toast.MakeText(v.Context, "Click : " + ((Email)mEmails[position]).date + "---" + position, ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }


    public void DeleteItem(int position)
    {
        mEmails.RemoveAt(position);
        NotifyDataSetChanged();
        NotifyItemChanged(listPosition);

    }


}
```

where i calling my bottom navigation view:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    public static RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    public static RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;
    public static BottomNavigationView bottomnavigationview1;
    public static RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    public static List<Email> mEmails;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerViwer);
        mRecyclerView.AddItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView.Context, DividerItemDecoration.Vertical));
        mRecyclerView.HasFixedSize = true;
        SetupList();

        //Create our layout Manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        RecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mEmails, this);
        mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);

        bottomnavigationview1 = FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>
              (Resource.Id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomnavigationview1.NavigationItemSelected += BottomNavigation_NavigationItemSelected;

    }

    private void SetupList()
    {
        mEmails = new List<Email>();
        mEmails.Add(new Email() { date = "9/25/2019", Subject = "Wanna Hang Out?", Message = "I ' ll   be around  tomorrow!!" });
        mEmails.Add(new Email() { date = "9/25/2019", Subject = "Wanna Hang Out?", Message = "I ' ll   be around  tomorrow!!" });
        mEmails.Add(new Email() { date = "9/25/2019", Subject = "Wanna Hang Out?", Message = "I ' ll   be around  tomorrow!!" });
        mEmails.Add(new Email() { date = "9/24/2019", Subject = "Wanna Hang Out?", Message = "I ' ll   be around  tomorrow!!" });
        mEmails.Add(new Email() { date = "9/24/2019", Subject = "Wanna Hang Out?", Message = "I ' ll   be around  tomorrow!!" });
    }

    private void BottomNavigation_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, BottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadFragment(e.Item.ItemId);
    }

    public void LoadFragment(int id)
    {
        Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (id)
        {
            case Resource.Id.bottomDelete:

                RecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mEmails, this);
                mAdapter.DeleteItem(RecyclerAdapter.listPosition);

            break;
        }

        if (fragment == null)
            return;

        SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
            .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment)
            .Commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to modify your code as follows

1.replace

```
public static RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
```

with

```
public RecyclerAdapter mAdapter;
```

2.just init value of variable `mAdapter`, not recreate a new repeated variable mAdapter.
So replace the following code:

```
  RecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mEmails, this);
```

with

```
 mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mEmails, this);
```

3.Remove code `RecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mEmails, this);`,because variable `mAdapter` has been initialized above.

```
   switch (id)
    {
        case Resource.Id.bottomDelete:
          // remove this code
          //RecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mEmails, this);
          mAdapter.DeleteItem(RecyclerAdapter.listPosition);

        break;
    }
```

**Update:**

There are two `bottom_bar_menu.xml`  in your app, one is in  `layout` folder, another is in `menu` folder, accroding to your code , you can move `bottom_bar_menu.xml` file from `layout` folder to `menu` folder,just overwritting the original one in `menu` folder.Besides,delete the one in `layout` folder.In other words, only one such file is kept in folder `menu`.

Inder to prevent code crashes,you need to add a judgment condition in method `public void DeleteItem(int position)` as follows:

```
 public void DeleteItem(int position)
    {
        if (mEmails!=null && mEmails.Count>0) {
           mEmails.RemoveAt(position);
           NotifyDataSetChanged();
          NotifyItemChanged(listPosition);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for aswering but even this changes it continues dont deleting, but dont show any errors just dont happen anything. Do you want me to share my app ?

Comment: @taniguchisantos  Of course,if it's convenient, being able to upload a demo is the fastest way to solve the problem.   ：）

Comment: thank you, here is a sample https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OJvN7_IH9sMczceO9WZcyidChcx65cHD

Comment: @taniguchisantos I have updated the answer, you can check it.